# Angular.js view rendering (with a bit more than just showing the retrieved values)

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I'm working on a view that allows user to type in the postcode and then it will give the location info about the postcode (lat, long, city name, etc), as well as marking the location on a map (using google map api).

For the postcod part, it is rather straight forward, I placed a few {{}} directives in the view and assign the corresponding values to the $scope in the controller. But when it comes to marking that location on the google map view, it gets a bit confusing. here is the sample code to mark a place in google map:

```js
var containerID = 'map-container'; // id of a DIV
var lat = 50.2;
var lng = -3.6;

var container = document.getElementById(containerID);
var options = {
  zoom: 15,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(container, options);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
  map: map,
  title: markerTitle
});
```

As you can see, the code itself only involves rendering the map, and to me it should sit inside the view because a view is supposed to take the returned result from the controller and do whatever magic it wants to present that result. And since the code involves manipulating the DOM, which is another reason I don't think it should be in the controller.

But am I correct to make this assumption?

And even if i'm correct, how could I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, DOM Manipulation should not be in the controller, but it shouldn't be in the view neither.

The Angular way would be to create a directive that handle all DOM Manipulation. This directive is independent and work alone, and is here to do the dirty job. Once you've created it, you add it in the view, and pass it the parameters from the controllers.

So the view display the element, the controllers set the model and values, and the directive handle DOM manipulation/graphic change,value processing ...etc.

Good news for you, I think that in your case the directive has already been made, you may want to take a look at : [AngularUI GoogleMap Directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api)

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your asynchronous codes inside.

```
  $scope.$apply(function{

})
```